# $R$ be an infinite commutative ring with unity such that for every non-zero ideal $I$ , $R/I$ is finite ; then is $R$ a PID or at least Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, noetherian

Let $R$ be an infinite commutative ring with unity such that for every non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$ , $R/I$ is finite; then is $R$ a PID or at least Noetherian ?

I can only prove that $R$ must be an integral domain.

Comment: I think Pete Clark studied rings with this property, but I don't remember what he called them.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : D you have any reference or anything that comes to mind . It would be very helpful . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is noetherian. Let $(\,\{0\}\subsetneq\,)\, I_1\subsetneq I_2\subsetneq I_3\subsetneq\cdots$ an ascending chain of ideals.

Then, by the correspondence between ideals containing $I_1$ and ideals in $\dfrac{R}{I_1}$, $$\dfrac{I_2}{I_1}\subsetneq \dfrac{I_3}{I_1}\subsetneq\cdots$$ must be an infinite ascending chain in $\dfrac{R}{I_1}$. Which is absurd, because it is a finite ring.

Comment: Ah yes , off-course ; now  should $R$ be a PID ?

Comment: Thinking about it.

Comment: I think , even if we only said $R/I$ is finite for every non-zero principal ideal $I$ , even then $R$ would be Noetherian , because if $I_1,I_2,I_3,...$ is a strictly ascending chain of ideals then $I_2$ would be non-zero so it would contain a non-zero principal ideal say $ Ra$ , then $I_2/Ra , I_3/Ra , ... $ would produce a strictly ascending chain of ideals of $R/Ra$ , which is not possible . Am I correct ? I am curious about it because I just noticed that to prove $R$ is an I.D. I only needed that $R/I$ is finite for every non-zero principal ideal $I$ ..

Comment: The proof you suggested of $R$ noetherian works. I don't know about the other part.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already show that $R$ is noetherian. However, $R$ does not have to be a PID. If $R$ is a ring of algebraic integers, then $R/I$ is finite for all nonzero ideals $I$. However, $R$ is a PID if and only if its class group is trivial. Thus, any ring of integers with non-trivial class group, like $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, is a counterexample.

Comment: Ah yes , off-course . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Noetherian:

Note that if $I_i\subset I_{i+1}$ then $R/I_i \supset R/I_{i+1}$, where all relations are strict.

Since $R/I$ is always finite and $R/I_{i+1}$ must always take something away from $R/I_i$, eventually for any increasing chain of ideals $R/I_i$ must become the zero ring. This means the chain terminates.

Comment: "$J\supset I\implies R/I\supset R/J$" does not really make sense: $\Bbb R[x]$ does not contain an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb C=\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$. It is true, however, that there are surjective maps $R/I_i\to R/I_{i+1}$ each with non-zero $\ker$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You are right that it is sloppy, if $I\subset J$ then the map $R/I \to R/J$ $[x]_I \mapsto [x]_J$ is a well defined surjective Ring morphism. Anything $[x]_I$ where $x \in J-I$ is sent to $0$.